# Combobox distinct - Linq c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo una base de datos con 10 datos iguales, usando un combobox me gustaria que se mostrara uno solo alguien sabria como he estado revisando y no logro funcionar el codigo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  comboBox1.DataSource = _entity.entradas.ToList();
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "habitacionid";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "habitacionid";
```

he usado un foreach, con linq distinct pero no funcionan

en la base de datos hay muchas habitaciones con el numero 111 pero solo quiero mostrar 1 sola que no se repita

update 1 :

```
var consulta = (from query in _entity.entradas
                           
                           select query.habitacionid).Distinct();



            //validar que esta arrojando la consulta 
                MessageBox.Show(consulta.ToString());
           

            comboBox1.DataSource = consulta;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "habitacionid";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "habitacionid";
```

Esta no funciona me muestra es todo el contenido de la consulta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

siempre me muestra es la consulta

update2

de esta manera el messagebox.show si me muestra solo un dato pero al usarlo en el combobox como datasource da error

System.ArgumentException: 'El DataBinding complejo acepta como origen de datos IList o IListSource.'

```
var consulta = _entity.entradas.ToList();



            var res = consulta.Select(e => e.habitacionid).Distinct();
           

            foreach (var result in res)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(result);
                //comboBox1.DataSource = result.ToString();
                comboBox1.DisplayMember = "habilitado";
                comboBox1.ValueMember = "habilitado";
            }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

finalmente lo solucione de la siguiente forma por si en un futuro alguien le pasa como a mi, habran mejores pero esta me funciono

```
     var consulta = _entity.entradas.ToList();



            var res = consulta.Select(e => e.habitacionid).Distinct();


            foreach (var result in res)
            {
//validar como que trae 
                MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
                


                comboBox1.Items.Add(result.ToString());
                comboBox1.DisplayMember = "habitacionid";
                comboBox1.ValueMember = "habitacionid";



            }
```

Comment: La lista de _entity.entradas como la rellenas? deberias poner alli solamente los valores que no se repiten, o hacer otra lista poniendo los valores unicos y entonces asociar esa lista al datasource

Comment: se rellena desde la base de datos toda como tal, pero cuando coloco id_multiencoder este toma solamente esa columna sin embargo como muestro alli hay datos repetidos, ese es el tema he tratado de usar distinct pero no me funciona

Comment: Y como lo trataste de usar? mostranos, asi podemos corregirlo...

Comment: adjunte lo que probe solo me trae es la consulta

Comment: Si entradas es tu entidad, no basta con hacer entradas distinct? tengo dudas de que tipo es consulta, y contra que tipos esta resolviendo el distinct.

Comment: en teoria deberia ser asi pero no me funciona, la tabla es entradas y alli la columna es habitacionid que donde tengo 130 usuarios que algunos de ellos tienen la misma habitacion la idea es que si hay 30 personas con la habitacionid = 111 solo me muestre en el combobox 111, no 30 veces 111

Comment: ¿Y si creas otra variable donde le pases el resultado de consulta y a esa nueva variable le aplicas el `.Distinct()` ?

Comment: eso intente pero me sigue arrojando toda la consulta como en la ultima imagen

Comment: esto funciona pero por alguna razon me da error al usarlo como datasource

Comment: Porque no es una lista, el datasource tiene que ser una lista... vos ahi, no estas generando una lista.. o por lo menos, no cuando haces el tostring

Comment: bueno en ese caso que se hace no se muy bien

Answer (score 0):

Desde el primer update estaba bien solo hacia falta el ToList despues del distinct para pasar la consulta a memoria, en este caso DisplayMember y ValueMember no son necesarios ya que la consulta retorna un arreglo de int32

```
    var consulta = (from query in _entity.entradas
                   select query.habitacionid).Distinct().ToList();

    //validar que esta arrojando la consulta 
    MessageBox.Show(consulta.ToString());
    comboBox1.DataSource = consulta;
    // comboBox1.DisplayMember = "habitacionid"; no necesario
    // comboBox1.ValueMember = "habitacionid"; no necesario
```

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.'